# Android volley to upload image

Tags: android, android-volley

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/) to upload image to my server. But it closes my app once I click on one of the pictures in my gallery. I have two buttons one to browse and the other to upload once the user made their selection.
To browse I do:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

And to get the results I override:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

**LogCat Error**

```
 01-06 17:32:02.937 24999-24999/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
    01-06 17:32:03.148 24999-24999/com.mypackage I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
                                                                                  Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
                                                                                  Local Branch: 
                                                                                  Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
                                                                                  Local Patches: NONE
                                                                                  Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
    01-06 17:32:03.176 24999-24999/com.mypackage D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    01-06 17:32:21.603 24999-24999/com.mypackage W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: I did. I have updated my question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I had

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

on the same activity when I was doing login stuff and later on I changed my mind and wanted to change my architecture completely and forgot to delete that line or make it false; hence when I had the result from the gallery the activity was gone from the stack. Now I deleted it everything is like it's supposed to.